# How to implement a simple String search

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, string, search

I want to implement a simple search in my application, based on search query I have.
Let's say I have an array containing 2 paragraphs or articles and I want to search in these articles for related subject or related keywords I enter.

For example:

```
//this is my search query
string mySearchQuery = "how to play with matches";

//these are my articles
string[] myarticles = new string[] {"article 1: this article will teach newbies how to start fire by playing with the awesome matches..", "article 2: this article doesn't contain anything"};
```

How can I get the first article based on the search query I provided above? Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would return any string in `myarticles` that contains all of the words in `mysearchquery`:

```
var tokens = mySearchQuery.Split(' ');
var matches = myarticles.Where(m => tokens.All(t => m.Contains(t)));

foreach(var match in matches)
{
    // do whatever you wish with them here
}
```

Comment: You would probably want to do a case-insensitive compare if this technique is used (i.e. so Matches matches matches).  ;)

Comment: do you know how does that compare, in terms of speed, with the use of regex ??

Comment: You can further improve this by using string.ToLower(). Then you don't have to worry about capitalization.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you can fine a nice framework for string search, cause it's a wide subject, and got many search rules.

But for this simple sample, try splitting the search query with " ", for each word do a simple string search, if you find it, add 1 point to the paragraph search match, at the end return the paragraph with the most points...